# Multiply values in a nested dictionary by values in another dictionary

Tags: python

I have a function that takes in two parameters

```
grocery_store(price_dict, customer_dict)
```

something like

```
grocery_store({"banana":0.59, "cheese":1.99, "milk":3.49},
{"customer 1":{"banana":6, "cheese":3, "milk":1},
 "customer 2":{"banana":1, "milk":2}})
```

should return the amount of an item purchased * the price of the item in price_dict, like so:

```
{'banana': 4.13, 'cheese': 5.97, 'milk': 10.47}
```

Here is what I have tried so far, but not getting the correct values:

```
output = {item: sum([val*price_diction[key] for key,val in price_diction.items()]) for item, price in price_diction.items()}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are not looking at `customer_dict` in the `output` you posted.

Comment: Thank you for the lovely post.  You put the question well.   This type of problem is what pandas was developed for.  I would suggest that you look at pandas especially dataframes.

Comment: What if the store also offers something but nobody purchased it?

Comment: This is my first post on here, so I'm glad I worded it well. I have heard of pandas but have never used it before, I will look into the documentation! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go! You can use the `Counter` for `collections` to sum all the sold products and than, retrieve a dictionary with the values multiplied by the prices.

```
from collections import Counter

def grocery_store(price_diction, customer_dict):
    counter = Counter()
    for prod in customer_dict.values():
        counter.update(prod)
    
    return {k: v*price_diction[k] for k, v in counter.items()}

print(grocery_store({"banana":0.59, "cheese":1.99, "milk":3.49},
{"customer 1":{"banana":6, "cheese":3, "milk":1},
 "customer 2":{"banana":1, "milk":2}}))
```

The output will be:

```
{'banana': 4.13, 'cheese': 5.97, 'milk': 10.47}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!! I have never used Counter before but I will definitely look into its documentation. Thanks again!

Comment: @JamesV99 when one of the given answer satisfies you, it would be the case to mark the answer as solved

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
price_dict = {"banana" : 0.59, "cheese" : 1.99, "milk" : 3.49}
customer_dict = {"customer 1" : {"banana":6, "cheese":3, "milk":1},
                 "customer 2" : {"banana":1, "milk":2}}

output = {item: sum(price_dict[item] * cart.get(item, 0)
    for customer, cart in customer_dict.items()) for item in price_dict.keys()}

print(output)
```

which gives

```
{'cheese': 5.97, 'banana': 4.13, 'milk': 10.47}
```

We can still use dict comprehension in the above case. Here's what this expression is saying in English:

- For each item in the grocery store, let `output[item]` be the sum of (the item's price * a customer's purchased amount) for each customer.

Not here that we use `dict.get()` to avoid missing key errors. Because we are checking every item in the grocery store against every customer's cart, if a customer did not buy said item, their dict won't have a field for it. What `get()` does is fetch the dictionary field if it exists and, if not, returns the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
def grocery_store(price_dict, customer_dict):
price_copy = prices.copy() # dont overwrite prices
  for food, price in price_copy.items():
    price_copy[food] = sum([a.setdefault(food, 0) for a in sold.values()]) * price
  return price_copy


grocery_store(price_dict, customer_dict)
{'banana': 4.13, 'cheese': 5.97, 'milk': 10.47}
```